# Parent's LayoutBuilder is called too often, every time a change in TextField occurs

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I'm seeing prints of "called" each time I focus a textfield, input or delete a new character. My real widget tree contains a list with its tiles having animations, that don't work properly due to the whole listview being recreated after scroll position is changed. So how can I still use what LayoutBuilder has to offer, that is `constraints` data, without having its whole child tree being rebuilt after something changes?

```
class _AppState extends State<App> with AfterLayoutMixin<App>
{
  AppCoordinator appCoordinator;
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context)
  {
    return Scaffold(
        key: Key("sadf"),
      body: new LayoutBuilder(
          key: Key("sadd"),
          builder: (context, constraint)
      {
        print("called");
        return TextField(
          key: Key("sad")
        );
      }),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: This is the expected behavior.

Comment: @RémiRousselet what's an alternative to LayoutBuilder then for my situation?

Comment: LayoutBuilder or the build count is not the problem. According to your description, the problem seems to be your animations/listview

Comment: @RémiRousselet not willing to modify the animations library at this time and fixing it through a layout builder would be easiest

Comment: You didn't explain what the problem with the animation is.

Answer (score 0):

You can assume that the build methods will be called excessively. If that's a problem, use a stateful widget and cache the widget you return from build.

```js
class _FooState extends State<Foo> {
  Widget _child;
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    _child ??= Container();
    return _child;
  }
}
```

This can be used together with Layout Builder.

Comment: That's a very dangerous thing to do

Comment: Why? Can you explain?

Comment: Using `??=` here means that the widget created will not update when the parameters/inheritedwidgets used by the widget changes. If there's a problem, the author should instead fix the problem properly instead of working around the build count

Comment: @RémiRousselet I replied on OP that other solution is to manually inspect and fix the animations library but that involves too much work for such a simple thing. What is an alternative to LayoutBuilder that works in a similar fashion for this situation?